# validate association sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model

```
const Faq = sequelize.define('faq', {
    id: {  type: DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
    title: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    is_node: {type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false}
}, {timestamps: false})
```

I want it to be impossible to create content instance if is_node is true how to do it

```
const Content = sequelize.define('content', {
  id: {  type: DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
  type: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, validate: {
    isIn: {
    args: [['img', 'txt']],
    msg: "Must be IMG or TXT"
  }}},
  content: {type: DataTypes.STRING, defaultValue: null},
  url: {type: DataTypes.STRING, defaultValue: null, validate: {isUrl: true}},

}, {timestamps: false})
```

this is a association

```
Faq.hasMany(Faq, {
  foreignKey: 'parentId',
  as: 'children',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  type: DataTypes.UUID
})
Faq.belongsTo(Faq, {
  as: 'parent',
});
Faq.hasMany(Content, {
  foreignKey: 'faqId',
  as: 'content',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  type: DataTypes.UUID
})
Content.belongsTo(Faq, {
  as: 'faq',
});
```

now i do something like that

```
import {Content, Faq} from '../models/models.js'

class ContentService {
    async create(c) {
        const parent = await Faq.findByPk(c.faqId)
        if(parent.is_node === true) {
            throw new Error('parent is a node');
        }
        return await Content.create({...c})
    }
}
```

I have read all the documents but have not found how to put it together

Comment: I think you can use hooks https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/